# Правильно ли тут используются потоки?

Tags: python, инспекция-кода

`bot.py`:

```
import json
import threading
from time import time

import websocket

client = amino.Client()

client.login(email=<email>, password=password)

subclient = amino.SubClient(comId=<comid>, profile=client.profile)

last = [time()]


def on_message(ws, data):
    if time() - float(last[0]) < 420:
        data = json.loads(data)
        if data["t"] == 1000:
            msg = data["o"]["chatMessage"]["content"]
            chatid = data["o"]["chatMessage"]["threadId"]
            print(msg)
            handler = threading.Thread(target=message_handler, args=(chatid, msg))
            handler.start()
    else:
        last.clear()
        run()


def message_handler(chatid, message):
    if message == "!hello":
        subclient.send_message(chatId=chatid, message="World!")
    return


def run():
    last.append(time())
    headers = {
        "NDCDEVICEID": client.device_id,
        "NDCAUTH": f"sid={client.sid}"
    }
    ws = websocket.WebSocketApp(f"wss://ws1.narvii.com/?signbody={client.device_id}%7C{int(time() * 1000)}",
                                on_message=on_message, header=headers)
    ws.run_forever()
```

`main.py`:

```
from lib import bot


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print("START")
    bot.run()
```

Вкратце что делает код: `main.py` запускает функцию `run` которая начинает обработку вебсокета. Вебсокет отправляет новые сообщения со всех чатов в которых состоит авторизованный пользователь.
Функция `on_message` проверяет не прошло ли 7 минут с момента последнего запуска `run`, это сделано потому что сокет через 8 минут перестает получать сообщения с чатов. Пробовал пингонуть вебсокет разными способами, но это не помогло. Далее она обрабатывает полученные данные с сокета и отправляет текст сообщения и чат айди в функцию `message_handler`, которая в свою очередь проверяет не является ли поступившее сообщение командой. Вопрос: если в двух или более разных чатах в одно время отправится команда !hello, запустится несколько потоков одновременно, или они будут ждать окончания работы потоков и таким образом образуя очередь? Хотел бы узнать как сделать так, чтобы бот отвечал на команды одновременно, если в нескольких чатах одновременно отправится команда. + рекомендации по улучшению кода

Answer (score 1):

Первая явная проблема в том что нет join на handler и обработчик завершается. Запущенный так тред может упасть в любой момент, как только GC начнет очищать его контекст.

Работай через пул, в глобале

```
from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool

pool = Pool(20)
```

В хандлере запускай

```
pool.apply_async(message_handler, (chatid, msg))
```